# How can I find out which procedure threw an exception in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, exception

I am using Delphi TApplication.OnException Event to catch unhandled exceptions

This works well but does not give sufficient information about where the exception happened 
i.e.  ‘Catastrophic failure’

How can I find out which procedure made the error happened?

```
procedure TFrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnException := MyExceptionHandler;
end;

procedure TFrmMain.MyExceptionHandler(Sender : TObject; E : Exception );
begin
  LogException (E.Message);     
  Application.ShowException( E );
end;
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get the memory address where the exception was thrown by using the ExceptAddr variable (System unit). But if you want a stack trace you could use one of the 3rdParty tools MadExcept, EurekaLog or the open source JCLDebug (part of the JCL).

Answer (score 9):

The simplest and quickest way would be to use the [JCL](http://jcl.sf.net/) exception and debugging support. After installing the JCL, make sure to insert the debug symbols into the binary (Projects -> JCL debug expert -> Insert JDBG data for this binary -> Enabled) and add a JCL exception dialog to the project (File -> New... -> Dialogs -> Exception dialog).

If the JCL installer fails to add that dialog to the object repository and it doesn't appear (happened to me a few times), either add it manually by copying the .pas and .dpr file from `jcl-install-dir\experts\debug\dialog` into your project and adding them manually, or close Delphi, edit `%DELHPIDIR%\bin\delphi32.dro` in a text editor and add something like this to it (adjusting the paths of course:)

```
[P:\DELPHI11\EXTERNALLIB\JCL\EXPERTS\DEBUG\DIALOG\EXCEPTDLG]
Type=FormTemplate
Name=Exception Dialog
Page=Dialogs
Icon=P:\DELPHI11\EXTERNALLIB\JCL\EXPERTS\DEBUG\DIALOG\EXCEPTDLG.ICO
Description=JCL Application exception dialog
Author=Project JEDI
DefaultMainForm=0
DefaultNewForm=0
Ancestor=

[P:\DELPHI11\EXTERNALLIB\JCL\EXPERTS\DEBUG\DIALOG\EXCEPTDLGMAIL]
Type=FormTemplate
Name=Exception Dialog with Send
Page=Dialogs
Icon=P:\DELPHI11\EXTERNALLIB\JCL\EXPERTS\DEBUG\DIALOG\EXCEPTDLGMAIL.ICO
Description=JCL Application exception dialog
Author=Project JEDI
DefaultMainForm=0
DefaultNewForm=0
Ancestor=
```

Answer (score 7):

Mostly related: [Exception Handling in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562/exception-handling-in-delphi).