# Exceptional Magic

Tags: delphi, exception

According to the [DimusWare site](http://www.dimusware.com/), Exceptional Magic was tested through Delphi version 2006. Does Exceptional Magic work with Delphi 2007? If not, does Delphi 2007/2009 provide the same or very similar features to Exceptional Magic?

Answer (score 7):

You may be able to get Exceptional Magic to work with Delphi 2007, but I think you'd be better off using madExcept by Mathias Rauen at: http://www.madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm

It's been upgraded right to Delphi 2009 and many good things have been said about it. It is free for non-commercial use, and $100 for commercial use.

Also see: [How can I find out which exceptions a Delphi function might throw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562/exception-handling-in-delphi)

As far as Exception improvements in Delphi, Delphi 2007 fixed a problem with constructors and destructors. In Delphi 2009 there are some new exception classes. But these are not major improvements and will not enable you to do what a third-party exception handler will do.

Comment: He wants to know if Exceptional Magic works with Delphi *2007* and not with Delphi *2009*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, plainth. I've adjusted my answer to account for this.

Comment: I had assumed that it was not compatible with Delphi 2009. However, if I'm wrong, that would be good to know as well.

Comment: Many pre-2009 components will still work in Delphi 2009. The main difference is the switch of default strings from ansi to unicode. As long as there is no code that uses an assumption that characters are 1 byte long, for allocating memory or buffers, or directly accessing parts of the string, then it should be okay. I converted some components for Delphi 4 all the way to Delphi 2009 without much problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should work. D2007 is binary compatible with D2006.

Also, you can look at other alternatives: JEDI's JCL+JVCL is free and it has a very nice exception handling engine. Even CodeGear/Embarcadero uses it in the IDE from D2007 time frame till now.

Answer (score 2):

We've been using Exceptional Magic in Delphi 2007 for 4 months now in our latest Beta version and we haven't seen any problems.  This version of our software is used heavily by our engineering department (20 developers) and tested daily in our QA department (10 testers).