# How can I log events to the event log and optionally to a file easily with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, event-log

I'm primarily looking for suggestions on logging components or libraries that are available at low or no cost. I have a Windows service and a client application that both need support for logging to a file. The service needs to also support logging the exact same messages to the event log as well.

I can write something, but if this wheel already exists it would be helpful!

UPDATE:
Turns out my question is a duplicate:

- [What's the Best Logging Package for Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84798/whats-the-best-logging-package-for-delphi)
- [Which logging library is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72983/which-logging-library-is-better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [Log4D](http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4d/) open source library:

it requires only one file (Log4D.pas), allows dynamic configuration in code and external configuration through a properties file (flat or XML), and is very easy to use and extend - writing a new appender class which can be configured from the properties file is simple.

Answer (score 1):

For the open source alternative, it sounds like you need the extensible [Log4Delphi](http://log4delphi.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I also just found this one:  [TraceTool](http://tracetool.sourceforge.net/)
Short description from the source site:

> The Swiss-Army knife of trace
>
> A C#, C++, Delphi, ActiveX and Java
>   trace framework and a trace viewer:
>   Tail, outputDebugString, event log,
>   and with Log4J, Log4Net

This came from a similar StackOverflow question
[Which logging library is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72983/which-logging-library-is-better)

There's also another similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84798/whats-the-best-logging-package-for-delphi

Answer (score 1):

this question has been asked many times, and some got really good answers:
[Which logging library is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72983/which-logging-library-is-better)

and

[How can I find out which exceptions a Delphi function might throw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72562/exception-handling-in-delphi)

Answer (score 0):

For a commercial solution (and commercial costs), the oldest (?) is [CodeSite](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/CodeSite/Default.asp) from Raize.